# How to edit specific column in MVVM kendo grid?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-mvvm

I am working on a requirement where I need to edit one column in kendo grid. But here in grid we have some column showing up based on condition. the issue is when we edit column it starts with hidden column.

[image]

after editing item column it shows **AreSkusInUse** column :
[image]

Here is my MVVM code:

```
<div id="BomEditorGrid"
 class=""
 data-role="grid"
 data-resizable="true"
 data-sortable="false"
 data-filterable='{ "extra":false, "operators": { "string": { "contains":"Contains", "doesnotcontain" : "Does not contain", "startswith":"Starts with", "endswith": "Ends with", "eq": "Equal to", "neq" : "Not equal to" } }}'
 data-bind="source: bomEditorDataSource"
 data-editable='{"mode": "incell", "template": kendo.template($("#bomEditorEditTemplate").html()) }'
 data-row-template="bomEditorRowTemplate"
 data-alt-row-template="bomEditorAltRowTemplate"
 data-columns='[
 {"field": "Selected", "title": "Selected", "filterable": false , "sortable": false, "headerTemplate": kendo.template($("#gridHeaderWithCheckboxTemplate").html()), width: 100},
 {"field": "AreSkusInUse",  "title": "SKUs In Use", hidden: true},
 {"field": "ItemCd",  "title": "Item Code"},
 {"field": "DesignItemNm",  "title": "Item"},
 {"field": "ChildQty",  "title": "Child Qty", "filterable": false, width: 100},
 {"field": "TemplateDsc",  "title": "Template"},
 {"field": "ParentItemNm", "title": "Parent", hidden: true},
 {"field": "CreatedByBookNm",  "title": "Created By"},
 {"field": "MaterialTypeCd",  "title": "Material Type", hidden: true, "template": kendo.template($("#MaterialTypeColumnTemplate").html())},
 {"field": "DesignGroup", "title": "DesignGroup", hidden: true},
 {"field": "CrudType", "title": "Change", "filterable": false}
 ]'>
```

here is the editor template:

```
<script id="bomEditorEditTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-tmpl">
<tr data-uid='#= uid #'>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="cb-itemSelected" data-bind='checked:Selected' /></td>
    # if (BomEditorType === "PFAM") {#
    <td>#: AreSkusInUse #</td>
    #}#
    <td>#: ItemCd #</td>
    <td>#: DesignItemNm #</td>
    <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: ChildQty" /></td>
    # if (MaterialTypeCd !== "DIEN" && MaterialTypeCd !== "FERT") {#
    <td>#: TemplateDsc #</td>
    #}#
    <td>#: CreatedByBookNm #</td>
    # if (BomEditorType === "FERT") {#
    <td>#: MaterialTypeCd #</td>
    #}#
    <td> <img data-bind="attr:{ class: ChangeIndicatorCssClass}" src="/5/DesignItem/Content/Images/Transparent.gif" /> </td>
</tr>
```

Here we can see **AreSkusInUse** column is showing based on condition.

So I need two help:
how to make all columns other than Child Qty to editable false.
how can i solve edit issue. When edit it should show respective filed data.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

1. "how to make all columns other than Child Qty to editable false"

   You can set the schema to set the field to editable: false

   ```
   ItemCd: { type: "string", editable: false }
   ```
2. "how can i solve edit issue. When edit it should show respective filed data."

    Specify the field value in your template

   ```
   <tr data-uid='#=uid#'>
     <td>
       <input type="number" value="#:ChildQty#" data-bind="value: ChildQty">
     </td>
   </tr>
   ```